# Kivy Escape Characters

Tags: escaping, kivy, kivy-language

I have a `.kv` file containing among many widgets a `label` and I wish to contain a `%` symbol within the text string.

My string is currently in this format:

```
Label:
    text: 'Brightness: %s ' % int(s1.value) if s1.value else 'Slider not set'
```

and this works fine. However, I wish to add the `%` value after the value so that the string appears like this:

> Brightness: 75 %

I have tried `escaping` the `%` character using `\` and `' '` but I always receive the error:

> ValueError: incomplete format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use % to escape % ->

```
'Brightness: %s%% ' % int(s1.value)
```

%% will always be ignored :)

Comment: I have tested this in kivy 2.1 and observed a strange behavior: i want to pass an already formatted string to a StringProperty: "34 %". If I don't escape the % character, kivy hangs. By the other way, if I escape the % character ("34 %%"), kivy renders "34 %%" on the screen, as it was not escaping the character.

Answer (score 0):

Use **%%** to escape the % sign.

This has actually nothing to do with **kivy**, but with python, more exactly string formatting using the percent ( % ) sign.

You can read some more [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python25/web/str-format.html).